# How to format decimal using JsRender templates

Tags: javascript, jsrender

i am using JsRender templates in my cshtml page. I have some decimal values in my data and want to show 2 numbers afer comma like 17,89 or 3,00. When i have 3 in my data it show only 3 in my template.

How can i format my decimal data?

Just a little example from my template that show how i use data  {{>rate}}

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `rate` is guaranteed to be a number, you can use JavaScript `toFixed()` like this:

```
{{:rate.toFixed(2)}}
```

If `rate` could be a string, you can coerce it to number, by writing

```
{{:(+rate).toFixed(2)}}
```

If you want to make a better separation of code and markup, you can define a [*converter*](http://www.jsviews.com/#converters):

```
$.views.converters("dec",
  function(val) {
    return (+val).toFixed(2);
  }
);
```

And then write:

```
{{dec:rate}}
```

You can even make the converter smart, and accept a `places=n` property, to configure the number of decimal places:

```
$.views.converters("dec",
  function(val) {
    return (+val).toFixed(this.tagCtx.props.places || 2);
  }
);
```

then optionally specify the number of decimal places:

```
{{dec:rate places=3}}
```