# jsrender Format Decimal to show 3 places in table

Tags: jsrender

I have JSON data that returns all the numbers with 9 decimals.  What is the correct way to format the data to only show 3 decimals in each row.

```
<table>
  <td>LotNum</td>
  <td>Heat</td>
  <td>C</td>
  <td>Mn</td>
  <td>P</td>
  <td>S</td>
  <td>Si</td>
  <td>Al</td>
  <td>RB</td>
  {{for value}}
  <tr>
<td>{{:UD01_Key1}}</td>
<td>{{:PartLot_Heat_c}}</td>
<td>{{:UD03_Number01}}</td>
<td>{{:UD03_Number02}}</td>
<td>{{:UD03_Number03}}</td>
<td>{{:UD03_Number04}}</td>
<td>{{:UD03_Number05}}</td>
<td>{{:UD03_Number06}}</td>
<td>{{:UD03_Number07}}</td>

  </tr>

  {{/for}}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsRender accepts expressions, (see https://www.jsviews.com/#paths), so if your UD03_Number01 is of type number, you can do, for example:

`{{:UD03_Number01.toFixed(3)}}`

See a similar question here: [How to format decimal using JsRender templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627481/how-to-format-decimal-using-jsrender-templates), including some alternative approaches.

If UD03_Number01 is a string, you can coerce it to number using

`{{:(+UD03_Number01).toFixed(3)}}`

-- or else you can use string manipulation methods, such as `substr()`. In that case you may want to put your string manipulation in a [converter](https://www.jsviews.com/#converters).

Comment: I seem to get an error that it is not a function.                                                             
 Error while executing templating engine. data.UD03_Number01.toFixed is not a function
TypeError: data.UD03_Number01.toFixed is not a function

Comment: Ah - you said they were numbers, but it sounds like they are of type string. I updated my reply.

Comment: Excellent. That was it, it is all in JSON so it was string.  Thanks